# ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

Tags: python, multithreading, mysql-python

I am trying to make two calls to the database, calls are being multithreaded.  However sometimes the first call data may be empty, and therefore it gets an error: ProgrammingError: (2014, “Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now”)

when I call the second query.  Is there a way to clear the cursor without closing the database connection?

```
        # CHECK IF NO RECORD IN DATABASE OF SKU
            try:
                cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `amazon` inner join `ebay` on amazon.ASIN=ebay.SKU WHERE `ASIN` = "%s"' % (sku))
                data = cursor.fetchall()
            except Exception as ee:
                conn.rollback()
                data = None
                print "Ebay error", ee

            # IF NO RECORD ADD EVERYTHING
            if not data:
                try:
                    print "Inserting into ebay table: " + str((sku, float(price), int(quantity), itemID, float(cp_price)))
                    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ebay VALUES ("%s", %.2f, %.2f, %s, %.2f, %s)' % (sku, float(price), int(quantity), itemID, float(cp_price), True))
                    conn.commit()
                except Exception as ee:
                    print('DB insert error', ee)
                i += 1
                continue
```